# Java - JLabel components only show when resizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

When I run my code the JFrame Window shows the smallest possible version of the title frame, it needs to be resized in order to actually show anything.
Usually this is due to the lack of a pack() or setVisible(true) at the end, but not in this case.
This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Boolean[][] maze = Exercise4.readMaze();
    int row = maze.length;

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Maze");
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, row));

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            JLabel grid = new JLabel();
            grid.setOpaque(true);
            if (maze[i][j].equals(false))
                grid.setBackground(Color.black);
            else grid.setBackground(Color.white);
            f.add(grid);
        }
    }
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JLabel grid = new JLabel();` is creating a blank label, it's default size will `0x0`, so when you `pack` the frame, it's been packed down to preferred size of, essentially `0x0`

Consider using something like `JLabel grid = new JLabel(" ");` to start with, but I might consider using a "blank" icon of a specified size instead

You could also use some text and set the `foreground` (text) color to the same color as the background, but I'd personally use a transparent icon, but that's me

Comment: That will give it a size and show something on the screen - but also note that you're not supposed to add components directly to the JFrame - you should add them to the content pane of the frame (`JFrame.getContentPane()`)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Since when?  Java 1.5 provided the ability to call `add` (and `remove`) which were redirected to the `contentPane` automatically - it was one of the major features people looked forward to (in Swing).  Me, personally, I'd use a `JPanel` as the base component and add that to whatever container I needed - but I thought might be beyond the scope for the OP at this time :P

Comment: Cool, good to know. Never had to revisit that as using `getContentPane()` was drilled in sufficiently for me, but I see what JFrame does now.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It's not a bad thing, but Java makes me type so much stuff already, any typing I can reduce has to be a good thing :P

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `JPanel`and placing all the components within it, then adding the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.